# Hamburger lines not centered when clicking on button

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

What I am trying to do is when the `.btn-menu` is clicked, I want the two-lined hamburger to change to an X. However, the lines don't get centered when this happens. What am I doing wrong?

I have the following HTML, CSS and JavaScript code:

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-menu");

    // Create menu animation
    menuBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle("transform"); 
    });
```

```css
 .btn-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0.8rem;
    transition: all 0.6s;
  }

 .toggle-line {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 1rem;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .is-top,
  .is-bottom {
     transition: all 0.5s;
  }

 .transform .is-top {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }

 .transform .is-bottom {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="btn-menu" role="button">
    <div class="toggle-line is-top"></div>
    <div class="toggle-line is-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the piece of the puzzle you are missing is the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) CSS property. This tells the browser where the center of the transform should be located. I've updated your code below to get the effect you desire.

*(Note: I removed the `translateY` transforms)*

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-menu");

    // Create menu animation
    menuBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle("transform"); 
    });
```

```css
.btn-menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 0.8rem;
        transition: all 0.6s;
      }
     
     .toggle-line {
        width: 5rem;
        height: 1rem;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        transform-origin: 25% 50%;
      }
     
      .is-top,
      .is-bottom {
         transition: all 0.5s;
      }
     
     .transform .is-top {       
        transform: rotate(45deg);
      }
     
     .transform .is-bottom {        
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
     }
```

```html
<div class="btn-menu" role="button">
    <div class="toggle-line is-top"></div>
    <div class="toggle-line is-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just interested in how this works. Can you explain how this works in layman terms?

Comment: It's a little bit of geometry. The one point you want to remain in the same place when you rotate the line happens to be a quarter the distance in from the left and half way down the height of the line. This is because the rotation is 45 degrees. Try a rectangular strip of card and put a pin in and rotate it. (same is true for -45deg).

Comment: I think @AHaworth explained it better than I'd be able to. The numbers needed to place the center point do seem a little counterintuitive.